# Organize files based on year and month

Tags: python, python-os

I have a function that organizes files in a directory based on `year` and `month`. It basically makes folders with different years and within those folders, it makes folders with the months. I have managed to make it work till here. The files with the `creation date` corresponding to a `specific year` move to a folder with that year and then within those folders it makes folders with the months. The problem is I can't seem to move the files within the year folder into the month folder, the function creates the month folder but it can't seem to move it into the folder. Any help will be appreciated!

```
def month_year_category(folder_to_track):
    years = set()
    months = set()
    if check_files:
        
            for file in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, file)):
                    raw_time = os.path.getctime(os.path.join(folder_to_track, file))
                    year = time.ctime(raw_time)[-4:]
                    years.add(year)

            for year in years:
                folder_path = os.path.join(folder_to_track, year)
                folder_exists = os.path.exists(folder_path)
                folder_name = year

                if not folder_exists:
                    os.mkdir(folder_path)

                    for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)):
                            file_raw_time = os.path.getctime(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename))
                            file_year = time.ctime(file_raw_time)[-4:]
                            if folder_name == file_year:
                                source = os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)
                                destination = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                                moveIncrementing(source, destination) 

                if folder_exists:

                    for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)):
                            file_raw_time = os.path.getctime(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename))
                            file_year = time.ctime(file_raw_time)[-4:]
                            if folder_name == file_year:
                                source = os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)
                                destination = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                                moveIncrementing(source, destination) 
                                
            for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)):
                    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)):
                        raw_time = os.path.getctime(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename, file))
                        month = time.ctime(raw_time).split(' ')[1]
                        months.add(month)

                        folder_path = os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename, month)
                        folder_exists = os.path.exists(folder_path)
                        folder_name = month

                        if not folder_exists:
                            os.mkdir(folder_path)
                            
                            if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename, file)):
                                month_raw_time = os.path.getctime(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename, file))
                                file_month = time.ctime(month_raw_time).split(' ')[1]
                                if folder_name == file_month:
                                    source = os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename, file)
                                    destination = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
                                    moveIncrementing(source, destination)

    else:
        return "Could not move files"
```

Comment: Your function does a lot of things. Split it in several functions with a specific atomic task for each one.

Comment: Maybe change it up a little: run through the files once and extract the year and month from each; while doing that make a dictionary with (year,mo) for the keys and a list of filepaths for the values, `{(yr,mo):['f1','f2',...], ...}`; then iterate over the dictionary items making folders from the keys and moving the files into that folder.

Comment: @wwii thanks for the idea, I will try to make it this way